# Java + Redis Pub/Sub - help to choose a good Worker implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, redis, publish-subscribe, worker

I am designing a Real Time backend chat application for mobile devices and to do this I am building everything over Java (to deal with incoming HTTP requests ) and Redis (Pub/Sub). Now I am looking for a Worker and already took a look at tools like Resque, Python-RQ and even Celery (also offers Redis integration), but maybe things grow and remain difficult to manage. I want to keep things as simple as possible. Has anyone tried to use Jedis (redis java client) to listening messages from a Redis channel and started a new Thread to each message received? Was the performace bad? what if a had hundreds of requests per second? It seems a poor solution (simple Thread as a Worker)

The flow is (for android example):

1. Android client send a message to chat
2. My Rest webservice (tomcat) receives the message and publish (jedis) a message to a Redis channel [quite simple]
3. The Worker (?) process the message and deliver it to all subscribers over Google Cloud Message (simple http request)

So, any suggestions or experiences about Redis workers implementations or Jedis library? What do you recommend?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For those who wants a suggestion:

I opted for Python-RQ because of its simplicity. Too simple, well documented and solved my problem.

Regards.